# Contradicting example concerning the definition of homotopic paths?

Tags: algebraic-topology, notation, definition, simplicial-complex

From Rotman's algebraic topology:  In the picture below in example $7.16$, how is the underlined statement in red true given the definition above it?  The elementary move of $(0,1)(1,2) \rightarrow (0,2)$ should still apply but the book is saying they can't be homotopic?

Additional definitions:  Edge path $\alpha$ is a sequence of finite edges $\alpha = e_1e_2\dots e_n$.

Edge $e=(p,q)$ in a simplicial complex is an ordered pair of vertexes lying in a simplex of $K$.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hint:* The definition says "where $\{p,q,r\}$ lie in a simplex of $K$" - which simplex of the skeleton do $\{p_0,p_1,p_2\}$ lie in?

Comment: Ah, I see.  I was misinterpreting that to mean "where $\{p,q,r\}$ each points is in its own simplex in $K$, not as the set of points lying in the same simplex.